# Unable To Apply CSS To Table Cell

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have table cells with class=image to which I cannot seem to apply any CSS.  Here is my markup (nested tables) where the first table shows an example of a typical row:

```
<table class="outer">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table class="column" id="leftColumn">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t1">
                                <tr>
                                    <td><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="t1r2c1" /></td>
                                    <td class="image">
                                        <span id="s1" runat="server">
                                            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="p1" runat="server">
                                            </asp:PlaceHolder>
                                        </span>
                                    </td>
                                    <td><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="t1r2c3" /></td>
                                    <td class="gray"><asp:Literal runat="server" ID="t1r2c4" /></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t2">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
            <td>
                <table class="column" id="rightColumn">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t3">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t4">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t5">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t6">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t7">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="cell" id="t8">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table class="messages" id="t9">
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.outer
{
    border: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.outer td
{
    vertical-align: top;
}
.column
{
    border: none;
}
#rightColumn table, #leftColumn table
{
    width: 100%;
}
.cell
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    margin: 5px;
}
.cell td
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    font-size: 11pt;
}
.cell .image
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 7px;
}
.messages td
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border: 2px solid #FF0000;
    text-align: left;
}
h1
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 150%;
}
h2
{
    text-align: center;
}
th
{
    height: 24px;
    background-color: #2B60DE;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.gray
{
    background-color: #AAAAAA;
}
```

Nothing I do to .cell .image seems to be able to shrink the images below a certain size -- which is already much smaller than the actual images so I know some shrinking is already going on.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Could be the `line-height` or `font-size` preventing the `td` to become smaller.

Try setting the `td`s of the row with the image to `line-height: 0px` and `font-size: 0px`

Answer (score 0):

I put together a `jsfiddle` of your example at http://jsfiddle.net/9xLqY/.  The styles are being applied just fine when I remove the ASP components:

```
<span id="s1" runat="server">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="p1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</span>
```

So it must be one of these components that is forcing the cells to be larger than you want. You'll need to add styles for `#s1` and `#p1`.